# How to add an horizontal line next to the title of a group in a navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'd like to move the horizontal separator that separates between different item groups in a navigation drawer and put it next to the titles of the group.
let's say I have the following XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
            android:title="Principal" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Second menu">

        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/listOption"

                    android:title="List" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/favoriteOption"
                    android:title="Favorite" />

            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

which has [the following result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6RfC.png)

I would like to get a result where the separating line is next to "Second Menu" in way that it's positioned in the center. [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uicrB.png)